# How to reconstrunct a binary tree from an array produced by preorder tree traversal

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

I was asked to implement a preorder tree traversal function, that function should have returned an array representing the tree,
and then I was asked to implement a function to reconstruct the tree from the array my previous function returned.
Something like sending a binary tree from one pc and then receiving and reconstructing it on the receiving end.
The important part is that the data should only be transferred once, so I couldn't use the standard preorder and inorder combination.

In my solution, each node is printed, and then added to an array that contains all of the printed nodes, if a node doesn't have a left subtree it will print and add the letter "L", and if the tree doesn't have a right subtree it will print and add the letter "R" to the array.

That part was easy, however, I didn't know how to reconstruct the tree on the receiving side.
Any help or idea will be really appreciated.

Here is what I have done for the sending part:

```
class TreeNode(object):
"""This class represents a tree."""

    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def send(arr_tree, data):
    print(data)
    arr_tree.append(data)

def send_sub_tree(arr_tree, node):
    send(arr_tree, node.data)
    if node.left is None:
        send(arr_tree, "L")
    else:
        send_sub_tree(arr_tree, node.left)
    if node.right is None:
        send(arr_tree, "R")
    else:
        send_sub_tree(arr_tree, node.right)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2, TreeNode(4), TreeNode(5)), TreeNode(3, 
    TreeNode(6), TreeNode(7)))
    received_tree = []
    send_sub_tree(received_tree, tree)
    reconstructed_tree = reconstruct_tree(received_tree)
```

***EDIT:***

I have managed to implement something that kind-of works, but its messy and doesn't reconstruct the sent part perfectly:

```
def reconstruct_tree(arr_tree):
    node = TreeNode(arr_tree[0])
    print(node.data)

    if arr_tree[1] == "L" and arr_tree[2] == "R":
        if len(arr_tree) > 3 and arr_tree[3] != "L" and arr_tree[3] != "R":
            node.right = reconstruct_tree(arr_tree[3:])

    else:
        return node
    if arr_tree[1] != "L":
        node.left = reconstruct_tree(arr_tree[1:])
        return node

return node
```

Comment: With problems like this, it always helps me to scratch out the process on paper or a whiteboard to try to visualize it.  Start here: Where is the root in your array?

Comment: I understand that the root is the first element, and I have managed to do the left subtree correctly I think, however, I got stuck on the right-hand side, and the result is messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could do it. I have also moved your functions inside the class, renamed them, and made some modifications:

```
class TreeNode(object):
    """This class represents a tree."""
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def to_list(self):
        return [self.data] + (
                self.left.to_list() if self.left else ["L"]
            ) + (
                self.right.to_list() if self.right else ["R"]
            )

    @staticmethod
    def from_list(lst):
        def recurse(it):
            try:
                data = next(it)
            except StopIteration: # Only happens if list is incomplete
                return
            if data == 'L' or data == 'R':
                return
            return TreeNode(data, recurse(it), recurse(it))
        return recurse(iter(lst))

tree = TreeNode(1, 
            TreeNode(2, 
                TreeNode(4),
                TreeNode(5)
            ), 
            TreeNode(3, 
                TreeNode(6),
                TreeNode(7)
            )
        )
lst = tree.to_list()
print(lst)
# Reverse operation
recovered_tree = TreeNode.from_list(lst)
# Make that a list again to see if it is the same tree
lst2 = recovered_tree.to_list()
print(lst2) # Same as lst
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/SerialiseTree)

Note that you could use "L" for the right-side child as well, or "R" for the left one, as the position in the array already leaves no doubt about which child is intended. One special symbol is enough.

Comment: Rather than using an index variable, the recursive function could access an iterator over the list. Calling `next` on the iterator will modify it in place, so you don't need the `nonlocal` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about a general algorithm, using Wikipedia's example of pre-order traversal:

[image: pre order traversal from Wikipedia]

```
F, B, A, D, C, E, G, I, H.
```

Let's mark a `None` for a null subtree:

```
A = [F, B, A, None, None, D, C, None, None, E, None, None, G, None, I, H, None]
```

Now we start at the root:

```
F
-> have a left subtree so insert B
   descend
-> have a left subtree so insert A
   descend
-> have no left subtree
-> have no right subtree
   return
-> have a right subtree so insert D
   descend
-> have a left subtree so insert C
   descend
-> have no left subtree
-> have no right subtree
   return
-> have a right subtree so insert E
   descend
-> have no left subtree
-> have no right subtree
   return
```

But how do we know which index and node we return to? One way is to call a recursive function from the node that returns the next index to use (remember here and in the example that follows that `i` is a local variable):

```
f(node, i):
  # left subtree
  if A[i]:
    insertLeft(A[i])
    i = f(node.left, i + 1)
  else:
    i = i + 1

  #right subtree
  if A[i]:
    insertRight(A[i])
    i = f(node.right, i + 1)
  else
    i = i + 1

  return i
```

Let's apply to our example:

```
A = [F, B, A, None, None, D, C, None, None, E, None, None, G, None, I, H, None]

f(F, 1)
  insertLeft(B)

  i = f(B,2)
        insertLeft(A)

        i = f(A,3)
              i = 4
              i = 5
              return 5

        insertRight(D)

        i = f(D,6)
              insertLeft(C)

              i = f(C,7)
                    i = 8
                    i = 9
                    return 9

              insertRight(E)

              i = f(C,10)
                    i = 11
                    i = 12
                    return 12

              return 12

        return 12

  insertRight(G)  # A[12]

  etc...
```